# How to make text inside multiCell filled the whole table cell?

Tags: php, fpdf

I need to fill the text inside multiCell

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4572.png)

Currently i am using this code.

```
$this->SetX($this->xKiri + $widthBoxNomor + ($widthDalam / 2) + 3);
$this->Cell(15, 3, 'Address');
$this->MultiCell(0, 3, strtoupper($this->data_header [0] ['alamat_importir']), 1,"J");
$this->Ln(4);
```

I change the first value param into this

```
$this->MultiCell(10, 3, strtoupper($this->data_header [0] ['alamat_importir']), 1,"J");
```

But the result would be like this

[image]

While i want the text to fit the red marks part and not making a new line like the first pic did.

What could go wrong with my code ?

Comment: Why not post a [mre] ?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have line breakers in your **ADDRESS** string? like *\n*?

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov i have checked and there is no such as \n or \s or \t

Comment: @Gagantous Can you try changing the alignment from *J* to *L* or *R*. And also do leave the width to *0*. This way it will take maximum space

Comment: It certainly does look like you have line breaks in the address string. I agree with Luuk you should at least provide a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: You said: *"i have checked and there is no such as \n or \s or \t"*. Perhaps you meant this literally? So there's no `'\n'` or `'\s'` or `'\t'` in your string. However, these are [escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). You didn't state that the unescaped versions are absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all indications point to there being escape sequences in your input data I would suggest making a simple change to your code to make sure that there aren't any now or later. Change

```
$this->MultiCell(0, 3, strtoupper($this->data_header [0] ['alamat_importir']), 1,"J");
```

to

```
$this->MultiCell(0, 3, strtoupper(str_replace(["\t","\r","\n"],' ',$this->data_header [0] ['alamat_importir'])), 1,"J");
```

That change should remove escape characters and replace them with a single space.